# Mac OS getting error while code generating

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I am getting following error while doing maven install on gRPC code generation project.

Error:

Unsupported platform: protoc-3.11.4-osx-aarch_64.exe

Maven plugin config

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
    <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <addProtoSources>all</addProtoSources>
                <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>
                <includeStdTypes>true</includeStdTypes>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                <inputDirectories>
                    <include>src/main/proto</include>
                </inputDirectories>
                <includeImports>true</includeImports>
                <outputTargets>
                    <outputTarget>
                        <type>java</type>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                    </outputTarget>
                    <outputTarget>
                        <type>grpc-java</type>
                        <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.57.2</pluginArtifact>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                    </outputTarget>
                </outputTargets>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You need to use a newer version of protobuf. 3.11.4 was released before the M1.